# DIY Gigabit cable wiring

Tags: networking, cable

I have a Cat7 cable `Draka Comteq UC600 Super Screen 27 4P Category 7 S/STP IEC 61156-6 FRNC`. I wired with two RJ45 connectors using T568B on both ends.
The stripped part at the end is approximately 1 cm (0.4 inches) and the total cable length is less than 6m (20 feet).

The cable works at 100Mbs, but not at 1Gbps. If I use a factory made cable, Cat6 - 1m (3 feet) length, I can connect with 1Gbps.

Do you know what could be the problem? Can I use a Cat7 cable or should I specifically buy Cat6?

Comment: Cat5 ought to manage gigabit over that distance, so I'd be looking at something other than the cable type

Comment: I said I was using Cat7. I guess you're saying that if Cat5 can manage, then Cat7 should be able to do it too, right? To what else should I look into?

Comment: Usual issue is crimping the plugs. I still manage to get more poor connectors than I really ought, considering how long I've been making them. Cable tester would be the best bet.

Comment: honestly, at that lengths, you're better off buying a cable.

Comment: Which are the CAT of the RJ-45 connectors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the cable with a **CAT5e** and Gigabit works. So the cable was the problem.